# Running system call in rails causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, pdf

When I try to run the following code:

```
system("pdftk #{@@temp_file_path} output #{@@file_path} user_pw #{@@pass}")
```

I get this error:

```
Permission denied - /tmp/billing.pdf
```

I tried running:

```
chmod +x /tmp
```

But that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Step 1 is `ls -lg /tmp/billing.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this system call first fixed the problem:

```
system("chmod +w @@temp_file_path")
```

For some reason rails pdf-writer plugin generates files as read only.
Maybe it has options to override that. :)

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on /tmp (you can find this with 'ls -ld /tmp')?  Are you trying to create billing.pdf or modify an existing file?

The user executing your rails process probably needs write privilege in addition to execute privilege (which you were adding with the 'chmod +x' command).  Also, if there's already a billing.pdf file in /tmp, it would need to allow the rails user to read or write it (whatever you're trying to do).